# Using $.ajax GET not submitting request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, fancybox

I'm having an issue getting this code to work properly.  When a user clicks on the "Email page" link, it opens in a fancybox with the address input and a submit button.  When I click the submit button, nothing happens.  If I change the  to an input, the submit function works, but it doesn't send the email.  The form should be submitting once the  is clicked, but I'm not for sure what's wrong with the code.

header.php:

```
$(".emailPage").append('<a class="fancyEmail" href="#emailPage">Email Page</a>');
    $(".fancyEmail").fancybox({'overlayOpacity': 0.9,'hideOnContentClick': false,'frameWidth':300,'frameHeight':100,'onComplete':function(){
$('#emailPage > #send').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/emailPage.php",
       data: "page=<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" + $(this).parent().find('#page').val() + "&email=" + $(this).parent().find('#email').val(),
       success: function(msg){
         alert( msg );
            $('#fancy_close').trigger('click');
       }
     });
```

page.php:

```
<div class="emailPage"></div>
  <div style="display:none" id="fancyBoxHidden">
  <div style="display:visible" id="emailPage">
    <h1 style="font-family:Georgia;color:#98012e;font-size:24px;font-style:italic;;padding:0 0 10px;">Email this page</h1>
    <form id="emailForm">
    <input type="text" id="email" style="display:block;width:192px;" value="Email address" onfocus="this.value=''" />
    <input type="hidden" id="page" value="<?php echo $postID ?>" />
        <img id="send" style="cursor:pointer;float:right;padding-top:10px;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/btn_send.png" alt="Send"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cleared"></div>
```

emailPage.php:

```
<?php

ini_set("sendmail_from", 'info@vasari-lifts.com');
$message = "A friend has requested that you take a look at this site.<br/> <a href=" . $_REQUEST['page'] . "'>Vasari</a> - by Autoquip";
$to = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = "View this page from Vasari-lifts.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: info@vasari-lifts.com";
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($mail){
    echo  "This page has been sent to: " . $_REQUEST['email'];
}else{
    echo 'error';   
}
```

?>

Thank you!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make this changes:

Insted of this `$('#emailPage > #send').click(function(){` you can use the id of the image to handle the click event: `$('#send').click(function(){`.

```
$('#send').click(function(){
    var parameters = {
      page: "<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>" + $(this).parent().find('#page').val(),
      email: $(this).parent().find('#email').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/emailPage.php",
       data: parameters,
       success: function(msg){
         alert( msg );
            $('#fancy_close').trigger('click');
       }
     });
});
```

Comment: This fix didn't work at first.  I had to add this in quotes: "<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>", and now it works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you will need to traverse #send image from div id= #emailPage
This will suffice if you do not have any #send duplicate id defined on page.
Please check the JSBin demo here:

http://jsbin.com/yiwovuve/1/edit?html,js,console,output